# svndiff data contains backward-sliding source view

Tags: git, svn

When I run git svn fetch command , I run into this problem :

```
"svndiff data contains backward-sliding source view: svndiff has backwards-sliding source views at c:/program files/git/mingw64/share/perl5/git/svn/ra.pm line 312."
```

I tried to resume the run using the git svn fetch -rxxx:yyy (specifying revisions).
I also searched for the solution almost everywhere, but no luck.
There is a related question already [git svn clone failed due to Svndiff backward-sliding source view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24904329/git-svn-clone-failed-due-to-svndiff-backward-sliding-source-view), but no answer yet.